# Why does javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults() report a keySet.size of zero?

Tags: java, swing

I am experimenting with changing some UI attributes, fonts, colours etc, at run time based on a user's configuration file.

The Set object returned by javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().keySet() reports a size() of zero even though the UIDefaults object reports a non-zero size, as does its entrySet().

Using javax.swing.UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults() reports the same, non-zero, size for all three objects, as expected.

```
package test;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.UIDefaults;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class TestUIManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIDefaults uidef = UIManager.getDefaults();
        System.out.println("UIManager.getDefaults()");
        testUIDefaults(uidef);

        uidef = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
        System.out.println("UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults()");
        testUIDefaults(uidef);
    }

    private static void testUIDefaults(UIDefaults uidef) {
        Set<Object> keySet = uidef.keySet();
        Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet = uidef.entrySet();
        System.out.println("    uidef.size = " + uidef.size() +
                " : keySet.size = " + keySet.size() +
                " : entrySet.size = " + entrySet.size());
    }
}
```

The output from this code, on my Ubuntu system, is:

```
UIManager.getDefaults()
    uidef.size = 641 : keySet.size = 0 : entrySet.size = 641
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults()
    uidef.size = 641 : keySet.size = 641 : entrySet.size = 641
```

How can a non-empty Hashtable (UIDefaults) have an empty keySet?

NOTE: I'm asking this mainly to satisfy my own curiosity. Using getLookAndFeelDefaults() seems to give me the results I'm wanting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this into your function:

```
System.out.println("uidef.getClass()="+uidef.getClass());
```

This shows that UIManager.getDefaults() returns a javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults

```
class MultiUIDefaults extends UIDefaults
```

MultiUIDefaults overrides entrySet / get and other calls, this affects the values of entrySet vs keySet call, the latter is not overridden (from what I see of JDK14 source code)

Comment: Thanks @DuncG. I will have a look at the Java source and see if I can debug it.

Comment: In fact this JDK bug you spotted has been noted here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146330

Comment: Ok, thanks again @DuncG. Looks like I'll have to update to JDK15 when it arrives!